# How do you insert a newline character within the RegularExpressionValidator ErrorMessage Field?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, servercontrols

Consider this code below:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
        ID="MyTestId"  
        ValidationGroup="MyTestGroup" 
        ErrorMessage="You are a silly user. You entered the wrong format for this problem. Please try again. Using this format! ELRLDKX##Z"
        ValidationExpression="some unrelated regex"
        runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="MyTestTextbox">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Is there a way to insert an escape character of some sort into the ErrorMessage string to ensure that *Please try again. Using this format! ELRLDKX##Z* is on another line? I have tried, \n with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Validator is on a web page, so you can just add html code to the text, like a `<br />`

```
ErrorMessage="You are a silly user. You entered the wrong format for this problem.<br />Please try again. Using this format! ELRLDKX##Z"
```

Comment: This works well, however, another issue that I have run into is that the boarder I have for the error message runs onto two lines when I use it. Any fixes for that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean by that... But Validators have a `Display` property, maybe setting it to `dynamic` can help?

Comment: So, I set the display to dynamic. I then wanted to give my validators some "flair" with a boarder and background color.

What happened was I get something along the lines of:


---------------------------
| You are a silly user
--------------------------
You entered the wrong format........|
--------------------------------------------

Comment: where the boarders are running over to the next line. I tried using div with a run at server, however, the issue is that hiding the div causes the control to turn off.

Comment: background-color:red;
    text-align:left;
    text-wrap:normal;
    border:solid;
    display:block;
    color:black;
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    padding:2px;